# Laravel How to overload environment values dynamically

Tags: php, laravel

Is there any way , to overload few environment variables dynamically, i tried to overload in controller constructor which works fine , but in some cases when variables are loaded via config/services.php it does not seems to get the values which i overloaded in the controller, i suspect that the sevices.php is being called prior to controller constructor method, is there any valid way to load them dynamically on start of the app .

Don't want to do it via file instead run time.

Comment: why do you not want to change them in the file? These are **constant** values. If you want other global variable just create them separately.

Comment: Cause there's multiple domain scenario and each domain have some specific settings which needed to be loaded dynamically.

Comment: Here's how I figured out how to override env variables in Laravel Dusk https://stackoverflow.com/a/58473993/470749

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To set configuration values at runtime, pass an array to the config helper:

```
config(['app.timezone' => 'America/Chicago']);
```

https://laravel.com/docs/5.3/configuration#accessing-configuration-values

Comment: Thanks , i totally overlooked that option :) , it works now fine. thanks for the correct direction.